# Factories {create(:user)} create every time new user in new it block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

My code for test case

```
RSpec.describe "Normal days ", type: :request do
  context 'User ' do
    before(:all) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = DatabaseCleaner::NullStrategy
    end
    let(:user1) { create :user }
    let(:user2) { create :user }
    let(:user3) { create :user }

    it 'Check-In ' do
      check_in(user1)
    end

    it 'Check-Out ' do
      check_out
    end

    it 'get histories ' do
      get_histories
    end
  end
end
```

## Note:

## Gem list

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'factory_bot_rails', '5.2.0'
gem 'faker', '~> 2.22'
gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5.3'
```

**Rails verision: **

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
```

**ruby verision:**

```
ruby '2.6.5'
```

## **Actual result**

when i run the test case then every case (means when call it class)  users (user1,user2,user3)  changed.

1. When run **check-in** case

```
user1 = user.email => test1@gmail.com and user.id => 1
user2 = user.email => test2@gmail.com and user.id => 2
user3 = user.email => test3@gmail.com and user.id => 3
```

2. When call **check-in** case call then

```
user1 = user.email => test4@gmail.com and user.id => 4
user2 = user.email => test5@gmail.com and user.id => 5
user3 = user.email => test6@gmail.com and user.id => 6
```

## **Excepted result**

after run the all case user value same

1. When run **check-in** case

```
user1 = user.email => test1@gmail.com and user.id => 1
user2 = user.email => test2@gmail.com and user.id => 2
user3 = user.email => test3@gmail.com and user.id => 3
```

2. When call **check-in** case call then

```
user1 = user.email => test1@gmail.com and user.id => 1
user2 = user.email => test2@gmail.com and user.id => 2
user3 = user.email => test3@gmail.com and user.id => 3
```

Comment: I don't really understand what it is that you're asking here or what the issue is. `let` memoizes the value across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples. The records having or not having the same id's is really down to how you're cleaning the database between examples and if the autoincrementing counter is reset between examples. If I'm not misstaken `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = DatabaseCleaner::NullStrategy` does absolutely nothing so it don't get why you would expect the ids to be reset between examples.

Comment: Also what you're calling an "it block" is called *an example* in RSpec.

Comment: when I run the RSpec and then create a new user for each it blocks  but I want the user same for all it block 
it blocks means:  `it { code ... }`

Comment: @engineersmnky `let!` doesn't carry across examples. `let!` is used when you don't want the lazy loading behavior of `let` - the block is run before the example. RSpec by design doesn't actually have a construct that carries across examples. If you want to do that you would use `before(:all){ @foo = "bar" }` which is generally frowned upon.